# PHP Parse User Uploaded Excel File into MySQL DB

Tags: php, parsing, path, phpexcel

Trying to allow the user to select a browsed excel file from their computer. Take that excel file and parse through it then write the data to a database. I am having trouble getting the parse to work. I know I need to use...

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="uploader.php" method="POST">
Choose a file to upload: <input name="uploadedfile" type="file" id="uploadedfile" />  <br />
<input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
```

and my only question is that when I use the $_FILES["uploadedfile"]["name"] it only gives me the filename and not the directory of the file so how can I pass this to PHPExcel Reader. Isn't this just a string of the filename and not actually a file path?

Heres what I have in my uploader.php:

```
<?php

include ('/PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php');



$filename = $_FILES["uploadedfile"]['name'];
echo $filename;

$inputFileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($filename);
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
$objPHPExcel = $objReader -> load($filename);



$sheet = $objPHPExcel->getSheet(0); 
$highestRow = $sheet->getHighestRow(); 
$highestColumn = $sheet->getHighestColumn();
$data = array();

//  Loop through each row of the worksheet in turn
for ($row = 1; $row <= $highestRow; $row++){ 
    //  Read a row of data into an array
    $rowData = $sheet->rangeToArray('A' . $row . ':' . $highestColumn . $row,
                                    NULL,
                                    TRUE,
                                    FALSE);
    $data[] = $rowdata;
    //  Insert row data array into your database of choice here
}

foreach ($data as $param){
    echo $param;
}

?>
```

Comment: Either parse the file __after__ using move_uploaded_file() when you know which directory you've put it in; or check the ini setting for your temp directory

Comment: okay so once I get the filename I need to move it to a file location and then I can parse it?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need the temporary name to either read it or move it to a place of your choosing:

```
print_r($_FILES);
```

Answer (score 0):

Point the path directly and pass it to IOFactory:

```
$filename = $_FILES["uploadedfile"]['name'];
$fullFilename = PROJECT_DIR . 'upload/' . $filename;

$inputFileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($fullFilename);
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
$objPHPExcel = $objReader -> load($fullFilename);
```